# retrieve list of blobs on Azure Storage by regular expression or wild cards

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to do a search via the Windows Azure Storage API, to find all blobs in a particular container that match a regular expression, or a wildcard?  For example, search for all blobs which match `*11002232*`.

This would return say blobs like:

- 11002232
- 11002232.jpg
- /uploads/11002232.jpg
- /uploads/test-11002232.jpg
- ...

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not possible to do so through the API. What you can do is filter blobs by prefix and then apply any additional filters on the client side.